# How to upload theme files into a PPA?

Tags: ppa, launchpad, deb

I have a GTK3 and a Gnome Shell theme. I haven't created a deb file yet...

Can i please know how to create a deb file and upload it to the launchpad? Is there any good guides?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Packaging a theme isn't much different than any other kind of packaging. There are a number of other questions under the [packaging](/questions/tagged/packaging) tag that might help you out. There are also a number of links to [tutorials on the tag wiki](https://askubuntu.com/tags/packaging/info). The way that I learned packaging, and that I like to suggest to others, is to simply look at packages like yours. `apt-get source` something similar and learn by example.

Though, let me start you off in the right direction. (This answer is very similar to [my answer about packaging python scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90764/how-do-i-create-a-deb-package-for-a-single-python-script).)

Here's your basic source package layout:

```
my-theme/
    -- my-theme/
    -- debian/
        -- changelog
        -- copyright
        -- compat
        -- rules
        -- control
        -- install
```

Run `dch --create` in the directory to create a properly formatted `debian/changelog` entry.

debian/copyright should look like:

```
Format: http://svn.debian.org/wsvn/dep/web/deps/dep5.mdwn?op=file&rev=174
Upstream-Name: myScript
Upstream-Contact: Name, <email@address>

Files: *
Copyright: 2011, Name, <email@address>
License: (GPL-2+ | LGPL-2 | GPL-3 | whatever)
 Full text of licence.
 .
 Unless there is a it can be found in /usr/share/common-licenses
```

debian/compat can just be: `7`

debian/rules:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@
```

debian/control:

```
Source: my-theme
Section: gnome
Priority: optional
Maintainer: Name, <email@address>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 7)
Standards-Version: 3.9.2
Homepage: http:///www.example.com


Package: my-theme
Architecture: all
Depends: ${misc:Depends}
Description: short description
 A long description goes here.
 .
 It can contain multiple paragraphss
```

If you need a specific theme engine for your theme, make sure that you put that on the `Depends` line as well.

debian/install:

```
my-theme usr/share/themes
```

Now build it with `debuild --no-tgz-check`

This will create a functional deb package. Lintian is going to throw a few warnings regarding the lack of an orig.tar.gz, but unless you plan on creating a proper upstream project that makes tarball releases you'll probably just want to ignore that for now.

If you want to put different variations into separate deb packages, take a look at: [How to have Debian packaging generate two packages given an upstream source archive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17508/how-to-have-debian-packaging-generate-two-packages-given-an-upstream-source-arch)

How to upload to a PPA is [covered in more detail on Launchpad](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading), but essentially what you need to do is upload the files with: `dput ppa:your-lp-id/ppa /path/to/your/source.changes`

If you haven't created you PPA yet, that is [covered here](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA#Activating_a_PPA).