# What's the difference between dev package and ordinary package?

Tags: apt, package-management

When I searched `libmicrohttpd` package using `apt search`, I got this

```
libmicrohttpd-dbg/xenial 0.9.44+dfsg-1ubuntu2 amd64
  library embedding HTTP server functionality (debug)

libmicrohttpd-dev/xenial 0.9.44+dfsg-1ubuntu2 amd64
  library embedding HTTP server functionality (development)

libmicrohttpd10/xenial,now 0.9.44+dfsg-1ubuntu2 amd64
  library embedding HTTP server functionality
```

I don't know what's the difference between the package ending with `-dev`/`-dbg` and the ordinary one. What's the  between them? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In maximally simple terms:

- `-dev` packages contain files needed for writing code that links to the program
- `-dbg` packages contain debugging symbols, which as the name implies are used when debugging the program

You don't need these in order to use the program, just as you don't need the `-doc` package if that shows up.

For more info, see:

- [How and why to create -dbg, -dev, -doc packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182703/how-and-why-to-create-dbg-dev-doc-packages)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032398/what-does-the-dev-dbg-and-utils-mean